# display uploaded image in custom tab in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

hello everyone I want to display the uploaded image through the form in a custom tab in admin grid for that image name is stored in the database through that I want to display the image.

block/tab/Info.php

```
<?php

 namespace Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab;

     use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
   use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
  use Magento\Framework\Registry;
  use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
   use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config;
    // use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\System\Config\Status;

      class Info extends Generic implements TabInterface
          {
       /**
        * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
         */
       protected $_wysiwygConfig;
         protected $_productRepository;
        /**
          * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\Config\Status
       */
protected $_newsStatus;

            /**
           * @param Context $context
          * @param Registry $registry
       * @param FormFactory $formFactory
         * @param Config $wysiwygConfig
         * @param Status $newsStatus
       * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    Config $wysiwygConfig,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    // Status $newsStatus,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
    // $this->_newsStatus = $newsStatus;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare form fields
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{
   /** @var $model \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\News */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('bookfreelayout_alllayout');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('news_');
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('news');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('General')]
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField(
            'id',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'id']
        );
    }
    $fieldset->addField(
        'name',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'name',
            'label'    => __('name'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
     $fieldset->addField(
        'email',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'email',
            'label'    => __('Email'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
     $fieldset->addField(
        'height',
        'text',
        [
            'height'        => 'height',
            'label'    => __('Height'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
     $fieldset->addField(
        'width',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'width',
            'label'    => __('Width'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    ); 

   $fieldset->addField(
        'entity_id',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'entity_id',
            'label'    => __('entity_id'),
            'required'     => true,

        ]
    );
     $fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'image',
            'label'    => __('image'),
            'value' => '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" width="50"/>',
          'renderer'=>'Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer\LogoImage',
            'required'     => true,

        ]
    );  


    $data = $model->getData();
    $form->setValues($data);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('News Info');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('News Info');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

logoimage.php

```
<?php

  namespace 
  Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer;

   class LogoImage extends 
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer {

protected $_storeManager;

protected $_fileSystem;

protected $_modelData;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\YourModel $modelData,
    array $data = []) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->_modelData = $modelData;
    $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
}
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
    $id = $this->_getValue($row);
    $filepath = $this->_fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('images');
    $data = $this->_modelData->load($id);
    foreach($data as $file)
    {   
        echo "<img src='".$filepath."pub/media/images".$file['image']."' height='30' width='30' />";
    }
}

}
```

through this code form data is displaying now I want to display the uploaded image 
NOTE:- there are multiple images are stored in the database
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to Your form**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'contact_image',
        'image',
        [
            'name' => 'contact_image',
            'label' => __('Contact Image'),
            'title' => __('Contact Image'),

            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this field in your form :

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'image_database_field',
    'label',
    [
        'name' => 'image_database_field',
        'label' => __('Logo Image'),
        'title' => __('Logo Image'),
        'value' => '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" width="50"/>',
        'renderer'  => 'VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer\LogoImage',
    ]
);
```

Create `LogoImage.php` renderer file at `VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer` and add this below code :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer;

class LogoImage extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer {

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_fileSystem;

    protected $_modelData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\YourModel $modelData,
        array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->_modelData = $modelData;
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        $id = $this->_getValue($row);
        $filepath = $this->_fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('your image folder');
        $data = $this->_modelData->load($id);
        foreach($data as $file)
        {   
            echo "<img src='".$filepath."your image folder".$file['image file name which is in db']."' height='30' width='30' />";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: no output is coming

Comment: Upload your code which you added in your file.

Comment: form field  $fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'text',
            [
                'name'        => 'image',
                'label'    => __('image'),
                'value' => '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" width="50"/>',
                'renderer'  => 'Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Block\Adminhtml\Extension\Grid\Renderer\LogoImage',
                'required'     => true,
              
            ]
        );

Comment: i have edited my answer

Comment: Remove 'value' => '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" width="50"/>'

Comment: Class Magneto\BookFreeLayout\Model\Allayout does not exist this error is coming in compile

Comment: It seems like your model file not created.

Comment: i have created the model file can you please tell me the path of the model file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90538/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-ashish-ramchandani).